# Can I support Stack Exchange sites propely by only asking right questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Stack Exchange sites are about asking **and answering**. However, [as I mentioned before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180943/what-if-i-cant-answer) I can't help by answering because most of the questions are about something I'm not good at. I mean, everywhere.

Though, I can help by asking questions which weren't asked before, related to the theme of the site where it's asked and either might be useful for someone in the future or provides useful and constructive answers.

Is it enough?

Comment: @gnat Duplicate of a duplicate?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Seemingly so, people will often mark it a duplicate of a question not at the end of the chain if they feel the ones further up the chain are actually better. And of course you get the end of the chain for free

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asking good, well researched, clear questions is critical to getting good, well researched, clear answers. It’s an essential part of stack exchange. As such you're certainly helping.

As such asking good questions counts under ['giving back'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87165/how-can-i-repay-all-the-help-from-the-wonderful-stack-overflow-community) to the stack overflow community.

You can go further as a question asker by replying quickly and giving feedback on what helped you (by accepting solutions, upvoting good solutions and if an answer got you 95% of the way there commenting on how you got the last 5%).

Of course if you feel able to answer some questions go ahead, we love answers too, but it’s certainly not mandatory.

Comment: But isn't that a 'problem' if I don't answer, but only ask?

Comment: It'll raise eyebrows, yes, but there's really no harm in only asking questions if you don't feel that you're confident enough to provide answers.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt It's not a problem. Good questions have lasting value and search engines help other people find them easily.